# Website Azure connection on mulitple subdomains

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, nonce

We are hosting a website on our webserver. That website needs to connect to Azure/Adfs. Users need to login through Azure/Adfs to access some parts of the site.

But it only works half. I can connect on "customer.nl", but on "subdomain.customer.nl" I get a "NONCE error".

There is a "Startup" class, which inherits from "UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup" (an Umbraco override for the regular OwinStartup). The class has a "ConfigureAuth" method, which sets the configurationparameters. One of them is the RedirectUri, and it's set (via web.config) to "customer.nl".

The "startup" code:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Ip.Startup))]
namespace Customername {
    public class Startup : UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup {
        string redirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];

        public new void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            app.MapSignalR();
            base.Configuration(app);
        }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions(){ 
                CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
            });
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() {
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications {
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to login on "subdomain.customer.nl", I redirected to login.microsoftonline.com but I see a "redirect_url=customer.nl" in the URL.

The function to redirect a unauthenticated user is:

```
public void SignIn(string ReturnUrl = "/") {
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = ReturnUrl },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }
}
```

But changing the RedirectUri in this function doesn't change the 'Redirect_Uri' in the login.microsoftonline.com url.

If I login on subdomain.customer.nl, I get returned to customer.nl with the following querystring (I've decoded the URL):

```
https://www.customer.nl/?errormessage=IDX21323: 
RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'. 
OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, 
OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. 
The nonce cannot be validated. 
If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.
```

My guess is that the NONCE error pops up when the redirect_uri doesn't match the origin-url (subdomain.customer.nl != customer.nl).

Is this correct? And if so, how can I change the Redirect_Uri to the subdomain a user is visiting? Setting it on startup isn't the way to go, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

•   Firstly, I would suggest you to please ensure that **public DNS records exist for the subdomains** that you want to connect to through the base domain URL, i.e., ‘customer.nl’. The **public DNS records for the subdomains can be ‘A’ host records, ‘TXT’ records** but need to be configured correctly within your public DNS server and **pointing to a public IP address if independent web applications are hosted** on them.

•   Secondly, since you seem to use **Azure AD authentication in your website** for redirecting to the subdomain, I would suggest you **configure the redirect URI for the concerned subdomains in the Azure AD registered application for the base domain such that after successful Azure AD authentication, the web application gets correctly redirected to subdomain page as desired**.

For more information on the above, kindly refer to the documentation link below: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad

> But changing the RedirectUri in this function doesn't change the 'Redirect_Uri' in the login.microsoftonline.com url

`You can do the above by delegating the required API permissions and scope to the Azure function application in your registered Azure AD application`. Kindly refer to the documentation link below for your reference: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent

Also, the **domains for the authentication request and the response need to be matched as it stores the ‘nonce’ and the ‘state’ for CSRF login attacks mitigation**. Thus, I would like to suggest you consider the scenario below for different clients (as per your redirection mechanism) and take advantage of SSO: -

a)  **The user logs in into the first application (customer.nl). The callback URL belongs to this app**.

b)  **After processing the callback (on the ‘parseHash’ callback function), redirect the user to the subdomain URL**.

c)  **When the user lands on the subdomain URL app, the app will see that there’s no session for the user and ask Azure AD for authentication (either authorize () or checkSession()). If the user already has a session in Azure AD, there will be no prompt to the user and a new authentication response will be provided to the app**.

If you are using **universal login (as opposed to embedded login as above)**, when the user clicks on **“Login”** on the base domain URL (customer.nl) app, you send the user directly to the SPA, pointing to a login initiation endpoint (e.g.: - https://app.mydomain.com/login 1), and have the subdomain URL app start the actual login flow.

For more information regarding the above, I request you to please refer the below link: -

https://community.auth0.com/t/log-in-from-different-subdomain-produces-state-error/19116

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. I will read the links and see how far I can get with this. Azure AD isn't my strong point, and we don't even control the AD ourself.

Public DNS is working fine btw, all the subsites are working fine.